# Fetchxml VS2015 to VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, fetchxml

I created a fetchxml report in VS2015 which I need to open in VS2012. When I try opening the solution I get an error  error  : There is an error in XML document (33, 10).

Answer (score 0):

The Report Extension (required to build FetchXML reports) is now compatible with Visual Studio 2012.

[SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843) must be installed, together with .NET Framework 4.5.2

For more refer [this](http://www.crmanswers.net/2014/11/crm-2015-report-visual-studio-2012.html) document.